# How to pass a list containing a single string in python?

Tags: python

In Python, how do I pass a list that contains only one string?

For example:

```
def fn(mylist): return len(mylist)
print fn(('abc', 'def')) # prints 2
print fn(('abc'))        # prints 3
```

I want it to print `1` for the one string in the list `('abc')`  but instead it prints `3` for the 3 characters of the string.

Comment: `('abc') == 'abc'` or else we wouldn't be able to group things with brackets

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a tuple, not a list. To make a one-tuple, do this:

```
print fn(('abc',))
```

To make a list of length one, do this:

```
print fn(['abc'])
```

In your scenario, I think a list would be more appropriate. Use lists when you have a bunch of the same elements of the same type, and tuples when you have a “record”, or some elements of possibly different types and you don't need to add or remove any entries. (Lists often contain tuples.)

Answer (score 5):

```
fn(['abc'])
```

passes a list

```
fn(('abc'))
```

passes a string in parentheses which are ignored.

As other posters have pointed out

```
 fn(('abc', ))
```

passes a tuple.

Answer (score 3):

They are actually called tuples, and you can create a tuple of length one like so:

```
print fn(('abc',))
```

Answer (score 2):

when you use `('abc', 'def')` it means you are passing a tuple. 
A tuple with single element can be declared as `('abc',)` .

**note the trailing comma*.

passing value as `('xyz') or 'xyz'` are same. 
So python function `len('string')` returns the number of character.
also , `len(iteratable)`  gives count of elements in the iteratable.

So, you should use fn(['abc']) or fn(('abc',)) to get the required answer.