# Python Single Element Sets to JSON

Tags: python, json, set

I have a bunch of variables that I want to turn into a JSON object string. Some of those variables are Sets. But I cannot get this to work if the Sets only have one entry.

I have already looked at the following question, but I'm not working with literals, I'm working with variables. So it really hasn't been helpful to me.
[How to pass a list containing a single string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226988/how-to-pass-a-list-containing-a-single-string-in-python)

I have tried the following class to encode the data:

```
class SetEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
  def default(self, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, set):
      setLen = len(obj)
      if len(obj) != 1:
        setAsList = list(obj)
      else:
        setAsList = [obj]
      logging.debug("DIAG: IN SetEncoder with obj = %r ; setAsList = %r ; setLen = %s" % (obj, setAsList, setLen))
      return setAsList
    return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

And here's my code to try to encode the Set:

```
  # following is just to demonstrate the problem; no matter how I try to
  # set the single element set, the code to process it doesn't work;
  # I've tried set(("CAT1")), set(("CAT1",)), set(["CAT1",])
  countriesSet = set(["US", "DE"])
  categoriesSet = set(["CAT1"])

  body = {
    "ownerId": OWNER_ID,
    "countries": countriesSet,
    "categories": categoriesSet
  }
  bodyJson = json.dumps(body, cls=SetEncoder)
```

And here is my output:

```
DEBUG:root:DIAGDIAGDIAG: countriesSet = {'US', 'DE'}, len = 2; categoriesSet = {'CAT1'}, len = 1
DEBUG:root:DIAG: IN SetEncoder with obj = {'US', 'DE'} ; setAsList = ['US', 'DE'] ; setLen = 2
DEBUG:root:DIAG: IN SetEncoder with obj = {'CAT1'} ; setAsList = [{'CAT1'}] ; setLen = 1
ERROR:root:parseXML: Encountered exception - Circular reference detected for destination <Element 'destination' at 0x000002570535B728>
```

As you can see, that single entry has curly braces around it, whereas the working entries don't.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with simply:

```
class SetEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, set):
            return list(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

By `[x]` you're *wrapping* your set object in a list, not "converting" it.  (It's the unwrapping of this wrapping that is causing the circular reference)

**Re: discussion**

Just so we're clear, this is what I'm suggesting.  In no case am I losing the brackets around a single element (list/tuple/set):
    import json

```
class SetEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, set):
            return list(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


objs = {
    'one_element_list_int': [1],
    'one_element_list_tup': ("foo",),
    'one_element_list_set': {10},
    'two_element_list_int': [2, 3],
    'two_element_list_tup': ("bar", "baz"),
    'two_element_list_set': {11,12},
}

for (k,v) in objs.items():
    dump = json.dumps(v, cls=SetEncoder)
    print(k+": ", v, "->", dump)
```

Produces

```
one_element_list_int:  [1] -> [1]
one_element_list_tup:  ('foo',) -> ["foo"]
one_element_list_set:  {10} -> [10]
two_element_list_int:  [2, 3] -> [2, 3]
two_element_list_tup:  ('bar', 'baz') -> ["bar", "baz"]
two_element_list_set:  {11, 12} -> [11, 12]
```

Comment: The problem is that the JSON.dumps() ends up "losing" the Set:  
  
"categories":"CAT1","countries":["DE","US"]

Comment: @Westy a set [isn't a thing that json understands](https://www.json.org/).  You're going to need to convert it to something else to get a proper JSON (in this case, you're using a list, but you could also serialize it into a string, etc).  Then, you could implement a custom JSON decoder to create a python `set` from the serialized/whatever/proper JSON.

Comment: Right, I know JSON doesn't know what a Set is. But it can handle the list. What I don't understand is how not to "lose" the list when there is only one. The fact that there are not square brackets around the single entry is what's killing my service that we're calling with the data. What can I do that will preserve them, no matter how many entries there are?

Comment: @Westy just as I showed, use *only* `list(obj)` when `isinstance(obj, set)`.  In other words, stop caring about the length of the set.  Have you tried the code I posted?

Comment: Yeah, I had actually already tried the code you posted, and went back to it. Here's what I get when I turn it into a list:  
  
    "countries":["US","DE"],"categories":"CAT1"
  
All I want is a list to be formatted correctly when there is only one entry in the list. This doesn't seem like it should be that hard, but I have wasted so much time on this, and still can't get it to work.

Comment: @Westy Take a look at the edit to the question, and if you're still having issues consider updating your question with your code / creating a new one.

Comment: Actually, the more I'm looking at this, the more it appears that the problem is in the `requests` Python library. From my log messages in the Python program, I am seeing this:    'countries': ['US', 'DE'], 'categories': ['CAT1'],  
And in my Node.js microservice, when I receive the request, I am seeing:    "countries":["US","DE"],"categories":"CAT1"

Comment: Thanks, jedwards. You helped me narrow this down. I will create a new question.